# Having trouble to call a https web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soapui

There is one web service which i can call with SOAPUI successfully but in Visual Studio. Both of web service clients were generated by same xml(wsdl and xsd's) which i share below.

Below screenshot shows how i called the web service in SOAPUI successfully.
[image]

When i try the same web service with same wsdl and xsd files, having below error.

```
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 768 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><env:Fault><faultcode>E9810004</faultcode><faultstring>Schema Validation Error</faultstring><detail>https://10.152.29.21:443/bea/ws/gi/fi/getbalsinfocallback/v01: cvc-particle 3.1: in element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body of type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body, found &lt;NS3:FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRs> (in namespace http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/FIGetBalsInfo), but next item should be any of [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Fault, {http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/FIGetBalsInfo}FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRs]</detail></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>'.
```

[image]

Webservice wsdl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBack"
    targetNamespace="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/FIGetBalsInfoCallBack" xmlns:bi="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/FIGetBalsInfo"
    xmlns:head="http://www.sama.bea.sa/common/Header" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wbir="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/FIGetBalsInfoCallBack"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/FIGetBalsInfo" schemaLocation="../services/FIGetBalsInfo.xsd" />
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.sama.bea.sa/common/Header" schemaLocation="../../common/Header.xsd" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRq">
        <wsdl:part element="bi:FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRq" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRs">
        <wsdl:part element="bi:FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRs" name="parameters" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="RqHdr">
        <wsdl:part element="head:MsgHdrRq" name="header" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="RsHdr">
        <wsdl:part element="head:MsgHdrRs" name="header" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBack">
        <wsdl:operation name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBack">
            <wsdl:input message="wbir:FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRq" />
            <wsdl:output message="wbir:FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRs" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBackSOAP" type="wbir:FIGetBalsInfoCallBack">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBack">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/FIGetBalsInfoCallBack/FIGetBalsInfoCallBack" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
                <soap:header message="wbir:RqHdr" part="header" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
                <soap:header message="wbir:RsHdr" part="header" use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBack">
        <wsdl:port binding="wbir:FIGetBalsInfoCallBackSOAP" name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBackSOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://www.sama.bea.sa/" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Xsd 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/FIGetBalsInfo"
    xmlns:base="http://www.sama.bea.sa/common/BaseLib"
    xmlns:bi="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/FIGetBalsInfo"
    xmlns:gi-lib="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/GeneralInquiryLib">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.sama.bea.sa/common/BaseLib"
        schemaLocation="../../common/BaseLib.xsd" />
    <xsd:import
        namespace="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/GeneralInquiryLib"
        schemaLocation="GeneralInquiryLib.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="FIGetBalsInfoRq" type="bi:T_FIGetBalsInfoRq">
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="FIGetBalsInfoRs" type="bi:T_FIGetBalsInfoRs"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRq" type="bi:T_FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRq"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRs" type="bi:T_FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRs"></xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="T_FIGetBalsInfoRq">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Rqstr" type="base:T_Rqstr"> </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="InvPrty" type="base:T_InvPrty"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ThrdPrty" type="base:T_ThrdPrty"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AccQry" type="gi-lib:T_AccQry"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="T_FIGetBalsInfoRs">
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="T_FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRq">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="AcctsList" type="gi-lib:T_AcctsList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ShrsList" type="base:T_ShrsList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="T_FIGetBalsInfoCallBackRs">
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Xsd 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/GeneralInquiryLib" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:base="http://www.sama.bea.sa/common/BaseLib" xmlns:gi-lib="http://www.sama.bea.sa/inquiry/services/GeneralInquiryLib">
    <import schemaLocation="../../common/BaseLib.xsd" namespace="http://www.sama.bea.sa/common/BaseLib"></import>
    <complexType name="T_FIRsGetAcctsInfo">
        <sequence>
            <element name="FICode" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <length value="5" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="FIRsStatus" type="base:T_StatusCode" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ></element>
            <element name="AcctsList" type="gi-lib:T_AcctsList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
            <element name="ShrsList" type="base:T_ShrsList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
        </sequence>
     </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_FIRsGetBalsInfo">
        <sequence>
            <element name="FICode" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <length value="5" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="FIRsStatus" type="base:T_StatusCode" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="AcctsList" type="gi-lib:T_AcctsList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
            <element name="ShrsList" type="base:T_ShrsList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
        </sequence>
     </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_AccQry">
        <sequence>
            <element name="AccNum" type="base:T_AccountNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="IBAN" type="base:T_Flag" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_AcctsList">
        <sequence>
            <element name="AccInfo" type="gi-lib:T_AccountInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_AccountInfo">
        <sequence>         
            <element name="AccNum" type="base:T_AccountNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="IBAN" type="base:T_IBAN" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="AccType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="base:T_NSPC">
                        <minLength value="1" />
                        <maxLength value="20" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="JntAcc" type="base:T_Flag" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="AccCur" type="base:T_AccCur" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="AccStatus" type="base:T_AccStatus" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="Inst" type="base:T_FullName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="OpnDt" type="base:T_date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="ClsDt" type="base:T_date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="AvailBal" type="base:T_Balance" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>          
            <element name="TotBal" type="base:T_Balance" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
             <element name="BalDt" type="base:T_date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="PrdUsrsList" type="base:T_PrdUsrsLis" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
           <element name="RsrvList" type="base:T_RsrvList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_FIRsGetDepotsInfo">
        <sequence>
            <element name="FICode" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <length value="5" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="FIRsStatus" type="base:T_StatusCode" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="DepotsList" type="gi-lib:T_DepotsList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
        </sequence>
     </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_DepotsList">
        <sequence>
            <element name="DepotInfo" type="gi-lib:T_DepotInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_DepotInfo">
        <sequence>
            <element name="DepotNum" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="base:T_NSPC_Text">
                        <minLength value="1" />
                        <maxLength value="30" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="DepotType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="base:T_AnyType">
                        <minLength value="1" />
                        <maxLength value="200" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="JntAcc" type="base:T_Flag" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="DepotCur" type="base:T_AccCur" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="DepotStatus" type="base:T_DepotStatus" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="DepotStrtDt" type="base:T_date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="DepotDueDt" type="base:T_date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            </element>
            <element name="DepotBal" type="base:T_Balance" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="PrdUsrsList" type="base:T_PrdUsrsLis" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_FIRsGetLiabsInfo">
        <sequence>
            <element name="FICode" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <length value="5" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="FIRsStatus" type="base:T_StatusCode" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="LiabsList" type="gi-lib:T_LiabsList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
        </sequence>
     </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_LiabsList">
        <sequence>
            <element name="LiabInfo" type="gi-lib:T_LiabInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_LiabInfo">
        <sequence>
            <element name="AccNum" type="base:T_AccountNumber" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
             <element name="IBAN" type="base:T_IBAN" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="LiabType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="base:T_AnyType">
                        <minLength value="1" />
                        <maxLength value="200" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="LiabCur" type="base:T_AccCur" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="LiabInstsNum"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <minLength value="1" />
                        <maxLength value="5" />
                        <pattern value="[0-9]+" /> 
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="InstRept" type="base:T_InstRept" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
           <element name="InstReptTms" type="base:T_InstReptTms" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="InstAmt" type="base:T_BaseAmt" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="LstPymtDt" type="base:T_date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="LiabDueDt" type="base:T_date" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="TotLiabAmt" type="base:T_Balance" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="RmngLiabAmt" type="base:T_Balance" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="PrdUsrsList" type="base:T_PrdUsrsLis" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_FIRsGetSafsInfo">
        <sequence>
            <element name="FICode" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <length value="5" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="FIRsStatus" type="base:T_StatusCode" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="SafsList" type="gi-lib:T_SafsList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_SafsList">
        <sequence>
            <element name="SafInfo" type="gi-lib:T_SafInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="T_SafInfo">
        <sequence>
            <element name="SafNum" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="base:T_NSPC_Text">
                        <minLength value="1" />
                        <maxLength value="30" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="JntAcc" type="base:T_Flag" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="SafBrnch" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="base:T_AnyName">
                        <minLength value="1" />
                        <maxLength value="200" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="OpnDt" type="base:T_date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="PrdUsrsList" type="base:T_PrdUsrsLis" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code sample, although the screenshot is hard to read because it's so tiny, it does appear that you aren't passing `infoRequestCB` and are only passing the header. The message you get back suggests that the request is missing something that it requires - that would be the obvious place to look. When you call `FIGetBalsInfoCallBack`, pass the body object as well as the header.

As an aside, the service you are calling looks to be total garbage for a couple of different reasons:

- Who on earth designs a SOAP service to take all its parameters in the SOAP header, with an empty body?
- it's formatting SOAP faults as `text/html`, which is simply wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tom, Yes i agree with you, a total garbage but this is a central web service which all clients should call. Regarding the web service, I do not have any authority. On the other hand, body object has 2 parts (accounts and shares) which i pass to the service. (which they are all null)

Comment: Your code shows no evidence of that. The argument list to `FIGetBalsInfoCallBack` is `(header, null, null)`. The SOAPUI project indicates that an empty body is required. Your code doesn't set this, so the examples don't match.